# Block Elements Behaving Strangely

Tags: html, css, flexbox, block, inline

I am hoping this is something really simple that I am missing. I have two pages on a site which are almost identical on a site. Both contain a form elementand some headings and paragraphs all contained in a div with flex display.

On one page the h2, p, and h3 elements behave as expect (ie as block elements)
[Here is a link to this page](https://www.wholechildtherapy.com/wctcourses/bookingform.php?courseid=spd1a&date=06-03-2017&time=09:15)

The other page is setup exactly the same way (as far as I can see) but the h2, h3, and p elements are acting like inline elements.
[Link to other page](https://www.wholechildtherapy.com/groups/bookingform.php?groupid=foodex)

What is going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On first page `<p>` tag content is heavy so it is showing block, if you try with second page `<p>` tag conytent heavy it shows in next line.

It is showing like beacause of parent class `flex_div_container` has `flex` propery. So every element in side that div behave as `inline-block`

Comment: Ah ha! Thank you, I have added some extra text which seems to have sorted it. Thanks for the help.